# Controlling file downloads

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am building an updater for my program with the use of a TWebBrowser. OnCreate the TWebBrowser navigates to the given URL. To download the update, the user is required to click a link. When the link is clicked this popup appears:

[image]

So I was wondering if it was possible to:

1. Bypass that popup and allow for automatic download.
2. Set a fixed path that the file would download to.

Comment: Why you are using a `TWebBrowser` for update your program? Exist many better options like Indy, WinINet , WinHTTP and so on...

Comment: Agreed, you should not use the web browser control for this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component for that, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdHTTP;

var
  Url, LocalFile: String;
  Strm: TFileStream;
begin
  Url := ...;
  LocalFile := ...;
  Strm := TFileStream.Create(LocalFile, fmCreate);
  try
    try
      IdHTTP.Get(Url, Strm);
    finally
      Strm.Free;
    end;
  except
    DeleteFile(LocalFile);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

TWebBrowser isn't what you want since you aren't displaying active HTML content.  As was said before, there are numerous other options.  Basically you want a HTTP request.

Here's a very simple example using WinInet, which will need to be adapted to your needs (threading, status messages and so-on).

```
function DownloadURL(inURL, destfile: string): boolean;
  var
    hOpen: HINTERNET;
    hFile: HINTERNET;
    myAgent: string;
    savefile: file;
    amount_read: integer;
   // the buffer size here generally reflects maximum MTU size.
   // for efficiency sake, you don't want to use much more than this.
    mybuffer: array[1..1460] of byte;
  begin
    Result := true;
    myAgent := 'Test downloader app';
   // other stuff in this call has to do with proxies, no way for me to test
    hOpen := InternetOpen(PChar(myAgent), 0, nil, nil, 0);
    if hOpen = nil then
      begin
        Result := false;
        exit;
      end;
    try
      hFile := InternetOpenURL(hOpen, PChar(inURL), nil, 0,
           INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD or INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, 0);
      if hFile = nil then
        begin
          Result := false;
          exit;
        end;
      try
        AssignFile(savefile, destfile);
        Rewrite(savefile, 1);
        InternetReadFile(hFile, @myBuffer, sizeof(mybuffer), amount_read);
        repeat
          Blockwrite(savefile, mybuffer, amount_read);
          InternetReadFile(hFile, @myBuffer, sizeof(mybuffer), amount_read);
        until amount_read = 0;
        CloseFile(savefile);
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hOpen);
    end;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  // example usage.
  begin
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
      begin
        if DownloadURL(Edit1.Text, SaveDialog1.FileName) then
          ShowMessage('file downloaded.')
        else
          ShowMessage('Error downloading file.');
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: And given what you want to do (more specifically), WinHTTP/Indy/whatever might be a better option than WinInet.  It just depends.

Comment: Not downvoting, because it's right in spirit (anything is better than a browser for what the question is trying to achieve), but using raw `WinInet` in Delphi is just a bad idea when there are so many better solutions like Indy, [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html), [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/start), and others. Compare your code and Remy's for a simple explanation why this is so. :)

Comment: @KenWhite yes, there's really more options out there than you can shake a stick at when it comes to downloading files.  Really, I was just trying to show the OP something to get started.  (For the record, I use other things than WinInet, depending on what I'm wanting to do.)

Comment: As I said, not downvoting because you're right in intent. Your content, however, is bad unless there's a specific reason to avoid other (much better) solutions (including Indy, which has shipped with Delphi for years now and so isn't really "third-party" as such). It also uses outdated, non-Unicode techniques (`AssignFile`, `Rewrite`, `BlockWrite`, and a `buffer` and `Rewrite` parameter of 1 that doesn't consider `SizeOf(Char)` for allocation).

Comment: @Ken White: In fact, I personally always use `WinInet` and old-style Pascal I/O. And there is nothing wrong with that as long as you don't produce any bugs (and there might be other reasons that apply to professional developers, you know, developers that program in a company). Instead, I see several benefits of using low-level stuff. For one thing, I think it is actually easier.

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry. :) I must not be professional, because my software has bugs sometimes (even though I work for a company). While I respect your well-known skills, I disagree (and so do most people who've written about this, including Dr. Below and Remy LeBeau). The old style I/O is outdated, has many limitations (including support for Unicode), and is no easier than the TStream-based classes in recent Delphi versions. (And I've programmed in a company probably as long as you've lived, BTW. <G> And I've made my living writing code for more than 2 decades, so I guess I'm professional.)