# downloading csv files in delphi

Tags: delphi, download, twebbrowser

Using Indy Clients (IdHTTP) I can download csv files, if I know the actual web address of the file by using the following code, which works perfectly ([original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949965/controlling-file-downloads)):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
  var  
  Url, LocalFile: String;  
  Strm: TFileStream;  
begin  
    Url := 'http://www.cvrda.org/boats/cvrda_handicap/cvrda_ratings_2009.csv';  
    LocalFile := 'C:\cvrda_ratings_2009.csv';  
    Strm := TFileStream.Create(LocalFile, fmCreate);  

    try  
      try  
        IdHTTP1.Get(Url, Strm);  
      finally  
        Strm.Free;  
      end;  
   except  
     DeleteFile(LocalFile);  
     raise;  
   end;  
end;
```

http://www.cvrda.org/boats/cvrda_handicap/cvrda_handicap.htm is the web site and if I look at page source I get the href:"cvrda_ratings_2009.csv". Nice and easy.

But
looking at this non-Delphi example from Stackoverflow, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896989/php-download-a-csv-file-directly-to-the-memory-preferably-without-curl), the website is [here](http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=AAPL&ops=clear) , if I press the export button, I can download the csv file manually, but to programaticaly download the file, how do I get the whole url of the actual csv file? I can't find it anywhere.

So I guess my question is:
Is there a way to get the whole url of any csv file that is being downloaded manually in TWebBrowser?

**update**

What I'm hoping to do is download a csv file programatically. But I don't know what the url of the csv file is. If I click the download button, in TWebBrowser, to download the csv file, a popup appears. I then have to manually press 'save' in the popup. I hoping to do this programatically. If I know the url, I can use Indy, but because I don't know the url of the csv file, I have to use TWebBrowser.

**update(12Nov2012)**
Example 2
(This example needs a Tbutton and a TWebBrowser on a Form)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ovLinks: OleVariant;
  x:integer;
begin
  WebBrowser1.navigate('http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=AAPL&ops=clear');
  //wait for page to load
  ovLinks := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.tags('A');
  if ovLinks.Length > 0 then
  begin
    for x := 0 to ovLinks.Length-1 do
    begin
    if Pos('javascript:SRT_stocFund.Export()', ovLinks.Item(x).href) > 0 then
      begin
        ovLinks.Item(x).click;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Sam M's answer helped me understand a lot, and it works for many web pages, but not all. I have no idea how to make it work for the above Example 2. In the above example I can download the csv file manually, after programatically clicking the ['Export'](http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=AAPL&ops=clear) button. But to download the csv file programatically in this example, I still need the url of the csv file. Any ideas on how to get the url of the csv file in this case.

Comment: I removed the Indy tags, because your question isn't really about Indy, and added the `TWebBrowser` tag because that's what your question actually asks about using. (For other readers, the actual question is in the final paragraph: How do I retrieve the target of an `<a>` link to a `.csv` file in a web page with `TWebBrowswer`?

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the correction, I guess you can tell I'm a novice programmer. Is there something fundamental that I'm missing here?

Comment: Just that your question is about TWebBrowser, not about Indy. (TWebBrowser directly retrieves the HTML; it doesn't use Indy at all. It's an ActiveX wrapper around Internet Explorer, so it uses IE's code to handle downloading HTML and other files.) Or is your question really about using Indy, in which case the reference to `TWebBrowser` in the final paragraph is misleading?

Comment: @Ken White, It would have to be about TWebBrowser, because if a file is downloaded within TWebBrowser, after clicking a download button, the TWebBrowser would have to have the file url somewhere. But if Indy is used, you'd have to already know the url.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What exactly do you want to do now? You want to browse to a webpage with a TWebBrowser, and then intercept the download of a file, and then download that without TWebBrowser but with Indy instead?  And if that's what you want to do.. why? I think you should describe your overall goal.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick  Hi Wouter. What I'm hoping to do is download a csv file programatically. But I don't know what the url of the csv file is. If I click the download button, in TWebBrowser, to download the csv file, a popup appears. I then have to manually press 'save' in the popup. I hoping to do this programatically. If I know the url, I can use Indy, but because I don't know the url of the csv file, I have to use TWebBrowser. (Hoping this is a better explanation)

Comment: Ok, that explains it a bit more. I guess you don't have control over the webpage?

Comment: @Woutervan , the web pages aren't mine, they are just web pages on the internet. I'm now thinking I don't need to know the url of the csv file, but just need to insert the file name and storage location on my computer programmatically, rather than having to have to respond to the popup prompts.

Comment: @James, it's really hard to provide any meaningful answer when the question keeps changing. How can we help when you don't provide the information up front? Your second example is using a web page with dynamic content generate by AJAX. That requires a completely different approach from the first example.

Comment: @Sam, Hi Sam, yep, I agree. The problem was that I didn't really understand how downloads worked. So I am going to write a new question.

Answer (score 2):

After the web browser has gotten the HTML document, you need to loop through the link tags. Based on the current page formatting, you would need to compare the innerText on each link to see which one you want. Once you find the desired link tag, get the href property. This will not work if the web page is modified in such a way that the innerText of the link you are looking for is changed by the people who run the web site.

```
procedure Parse;
var URL : string;
    i: integer;
    Document: variant;
begin
  Document := WebBrowser.Document AS IHTMLDocument3;
  for i := 0 to Document.Links.Length - 1 do begin
    if Document.Links.Item(i).innerText = 'here' then begin
      URL := Document.Links.Item(i).href;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If in the future the web page starts using tag ids or tag names, it's even easier. Use the getElementById function and then there's no need to loop through all the elements.

Comment: thanks Sam for the code, it helped a lot, but there are still some web pages which it doesn't work. I updated my question to show where it doesn't work. I pressed the 'answer was useful' button for your answer. Thanks again. James.