# Getting "resource is busy" error, how to fix it?

Tags: windows, delphi, internet-explorer, browser

I got the below code, which I believe producing "Resource is busy" and since it is in a Timer keep on repeating. I use it to find out what the website I am trying to automate telling me and act accordingly.

Anyone can tell me how to fix the code or debug it?

```
    procedure TimerAutoOKTimer(Sender: TObject);
     const
          Messagefromwebpage = 'Message from webpage';

       var
          wnd: hWnd;

    begin
          wnd := FindWindow(nil, Messagefromwebpage);  // 'Message from webpage';
          if wnd <> 0 then
          begin
             Memo1.Lines.Clear;
             EnumChildWindows(wnd, @EnumChildrenProc, Integer(Memo1.Lines));

             if POS('NOT possible', Memo1.Lines.Text)>0 then
               SendMessage(Application.ActiveFormHandle, WM_COMMAND, ID_OK, 0);

             if Pos('The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window.', Memo1.Lines.Text)>0 then
               SendMessage(Application.ActiveFormHandle, WM_COMMAND, ID_NO, 0);
          end;
    end;
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: So, what is producing "Resource is busy"?

Comment: Not sure I suspect it is either SendMessage or EnumChildWindows?

Comment: Well, which one is it. Comment out the `SendMessage` calls. I bet it is them. My guess is that you need to use `PostMessage` instead.

Comment: Where is the window that you are trying to automate? Is it in your process?

Comment: It is raised by my process through WebBrowser. I tried swapping to PostMessage, same error. :(

Comment: So what is `ActiveFormHandle`? Which window is that?

Comment: It is a single Form app. I am using it since it is the only thing seemed to work when I send the message to the TWebBrowser Popup Window. I tried using "wnd" variable but for some reason it did not click...

Comment: Well, sending those messages to random windows isn't going to get it done.

Comment: I see. Must admit, it worked for a while :) 

1. So basically I will need to set focus on the  "wnd" and then click?

2. Application.ActiveFormHandle != the current form handle of my app?

Comment: You're already enumerating the children of the dialog, you can try finding the OK button to send a BM_CLICK message. It may require setting focus and clicking the button a few many times; I once had some trouble clicking a button of a ie window (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13496333).

Comment: Are you sure it's not your timer firing too often? Set a form property FInTimer to prevent entering the routine again while it's busy.

Comment: I changed SendMessage to use wnd and for now it works fine :) I am testing now. @David, Sertac, Jan thanks for your help!

Comment: @JanDoggen The timer cannot fire again because the message queue is not serviced during the timer proc

Comment: I realised it works for most windows, but one which only differs in  the text... Since it is not clicked OK, next time it will raise the error "resource is busy"

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I tried your code, It clicks and then stucks in a loop :(
`
                SetForegroundWindow(wnd);
                bwnd := GetDlgItem(wnd, ID_OK);
                if bwnd <> 0 then begin  // click the button
                  // the dialog/button is kind of deaf..
                  while IsWindowEnabled(wnd) do begin
                    SendMessage(bwnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
                    Sleep(100);
                  end;
                  wnd:=0;
                end;
`

Comment: @mod - Sure you've got a find a way out of the loop. Testing if the dialog is enabled was OK for that question, your situation is different. My only point was, ie dialogs might not register a click for a few times.

Comment: Managed to figure but still on of the windows not getting my clicks:
`ID: 2, ClassName: Button, Caption: OKID: 20, ClassName: Static, Caption: ID: 65535, ClassName: Static, Caption: Unable to Archive Product...`

THis is one work though:
`ID: 1, ClassName: Button, Caption: OKID: 2, ClassName: Button, Caption: CancelID: 20, ClassName: Static, Caption: ID: 65535, ClassName: Static, Caption: Are you sure you want to delete this batch item?`